# Angular web notification is not coming on another devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, push-notification, web-notifications

I am trying to put the web notifications to my site so that all of my clients will see my notification in browser, when I add any new item in my site.

I chose [angular-web-notification](https://github.com/sagiegurari/angular-web-notification), I installed through Bower in my app and tested locally, it worked fine but when I deployed my site to production, then I again tested in production, the notification is coming for only in my browser only not for all the clients who allowed the notifications for my site.

**Here is my code:**

```
.directive('showButton', ['webNotification', function (webNotification) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
      notificationTitle: '=',
      notificationMsg: '=',
      notificationUrl: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      console.log("coming to directive notifications")
      element.on('click', function onClick() {
        console.log("coming to directive notifications click")

        if ((scope.notificationTitle) && (scope.notificationMsg)) {       

          webNotification.showNotification(scope.notificationTitle, {
            body: scope.notificationMsg,
            icon: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/BCOE0vqCfr8aqpIKEF7QEt-qa7p8I7KDg58Juz6M6_YGb4l7phrO2vMvi_SDy10ucQ=w300',
            onClick: function onNotificationClicked() {
              console.log('Notification clicked.');
              window.open(scope.notificationUrl, '_blank')
            },
            autoClose: 4000 //auto close the notification after 4 seconds (you can manually close it via hide function)
          }, function onShow(error, hide) {
            if (error) {
              window.alert('Unable to show notification: ' + error.message);
            } else {
              console.log('Notification Shown.');

              setTimeout(function hideNotification() {
                console.log('Hiding notification....');
                hide(); //manually close the notification (you can skip this if you use the autoClose option)
              }, 5000);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: There is no error in your code. Did you allow show notification in your browser?

Comment: Could you share the live link?

Comment: yes i allowed the notifications in browser @Rishi

Comment: This sounds like your production application is configured to send notifications to `dev` environment (not `production`) and you have a development application up and running at the same time.